# Toggle specific div (id) within a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a site built with post-components to show articles in a feed. Inside the component, I have a button that opens a modal onClick. I use useState to toggle on the modal which works perfectly fine. The problem is that since the toggle is put on the modal-div inside the component.. every single post modal opens whenever I click one of the buttons. I want to open only the targeted post modal (with the sam post id as the button I’m clicking). I can’t figure out how to do this…in react.

```
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState (true);
      
    const toggler = () => {
        setToggle(prev => !prev)
    }


...

return (
        <section className="posts">
        {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map((edge) => {
            return (
                <div className="post">
                    <div className="postDescrip">
                        <h2 className="postTitle">{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                        <h2 className="name">{edge.node.frontmatter.name}</h2>

                        <button className="readMoreBtn" onClick={toggler}>{toggle ? <h2 className="readMore">Read more</h2> : <h2 className="readMore">Read less</h2>} 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                
                    <Img className="postImg" fluid={edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid} /> 

                    <div className={toggle ? 'hide' : 'postCopy'} >
                        <Close close={toggler} />
                        <h3>{edge.node.frontmatter.details}</h3>
                        <div className="copy" dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{__html: edge.node.html}}></div>
                        <h4>Read the full article in Issue One</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        )}
        </section>
    )
}
export default Posts;
```

After trying  suggested solution using object instead on bolean. I now receive this error message
[Error message][1]for the following code:

```
    const [toggles, setToggles] = useState ({});
    
    let id;
    const createToggler = (id) = () => {
        setToggles(prev => { [id] : !prev[id] }) 
        // setToggle(prev => { ...prev, [id]: !prev[id] }) // or support multi modal at same time. but I think you don't want it.
    }
    
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query {
            allMarkdownRemark (
                sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
                ){
                edges {
                    node {
                        frontmatter {
                            id
                            title
                            name
                            details
                            featuredImage {
                                childImageSharp {
                                    fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
                                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        html
                        fields {
                            slug
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    
    
    return (
        <section className="posts">
        {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map((edge) => {
            const id = edge.node.frontmatter.id;
            const toggle = toggles[id];
            const toggler = createToggler(id);
            return (
                <div className="post" id={edge.node.frontmatter.id}>
                    <div className="postDescrip">
                        <h2 className="postTitle">{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                        <h2 className="name">{edge.node.frontmatter.name}</h2>

                        <button className="readMoreBtn" onClick={toggler}>{toggle ? <h2 className="readMore">Read more</h2> : <h2 className="readMore">Read less</h2>} 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                
                    <Img className="postImg" fluid={edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid} /> 

                    <div className={toggle ? 'hide' : 'postCopy'} id={edge.node.frontmatter.id}>
                        <Close close={toggler} />
                        <h3>{edge.node.frontmatter.details}</h3>
                        <div className="copy" dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{__html: edge.node.html}}></div>
                        <h4>Read the full article in Issue One</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        )}
        </section>
    )
}
export default Posts;
            


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhIYF.png
```

Comment: Move everything you have inside `map` into a separate component with its own individual state, it'll be better than keeping track of toggle states of each element inside parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import './posts.css';
import cancel from '../images/cancel.png'

const Post = ({title, name, id, image, details, html}) => {   
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState (true);

    const toggler = () => {
        setToggle(prev => !prev)
    }

    const selectPost= (event) =>{
        let id = event.target.id,
            postCopy = document.getElementById('hide' + id);
            toggler.call(postCopy);
    } 

        
    return (
        <div className="post">
            <div className="postDescrip">
                <h2 className="postTitle">{title}</h2>
                <h2 className="name">{name}</h2>
                <button className="readMoreBtn" onClick={selectPost}>{toggle ? <h2 id={id} className="readMore">Read more</h2> : <h2 id={id} className="readMore">Read less</h2>} 
                </button>
            </div>
        
            <Img className="postImg" fluid={image} />
            <div id={'hide' + id} className={toggle ? 'hide' : 'postCopy'} >
                <button aria-label="Close" onClick={selectPost} className="closeBtn">
                    <img alt="close-button" src={cancel}/>
                </button>
                <h3>{details}</h3>
                <div className="copy" dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {html}></div>
                <a href="/#footer"><h4>Read the full article in Issue One</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

like this.
use a object instead of a single boolean.

```
    const [toggles, setToggles] = useState ({});
      
    const createToggler = (id) = () => {
        setToggle(prev => { [id]: !prev[id] }) // atmost one id is true. others is undefine or false.
        // setToggle(prev => { ...prev, [id]: !prev[id] }) // or support multi modal at same time. but I think you don't want it.
    }


...

return (
        <section className="posts">
        {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map((edge) => {
            const id = ... // get your id form edge.
            const toggle = toggles[id];
            const toggler = createToggler(id);
            return (
                <div className="post">
                    <div className="postDescrip">
                        <h2 className="postTitle">{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h2>
                        <h2 className="name">{edge.node.frontmatter.name}</h2>

                        <button className="readMoreBtn" onClick={toggler}>{toggle ? <h2 className="readMore">Read more</h2> : <h2 className="readMore">Read less</h2>} 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                
                    <Img className="postImg" fluid={edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid} /> 

                    <div className={toggle ? 'hide' : 'postCopy'} >
                        <Close close={toggler} />
                        <h3>{edge.node.frontmatter.details}</h3>
                        <div className="copy" dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{__html: edge.node.html}}></div>
                        <h4>Read the full article in Issue One</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        )}
        </section>
    )
}
export default Posts;
```